# ndk-build errors, string format, clang no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, clang

I've tried creating a simple jni test app from "Beginning Android Games 3rd Ed" book. I copy-pasted the code, but when I try to link with ndk-build, I get the following error messages:

```
D:\apps\android\projects\NDK\app\src\main\java>ndk-build
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm  : jniutils <= jniutils.cpp
jni/jniutils.cpp:8:52: error: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
      [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, cTag, cMessage);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~
jni/jniutils.cpp:8:52: note: treat the string as an argument to avoid this
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, cTag, cMessage);
                                                   ^
                                                   "%s",
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/jniutils/jniutils.o] Error 1
```

If I try to treat these errors as warnings and suppress these with the following lines in android.mk / application.mk:

```
APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security
LOCAL_DISABLE_FORMAT_STRING_CHECKS := true
```

Then I get this error:

```
D:\apps\android\projects\NDK\app\src\main\java>ndk-build
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libjniutils.so
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '遶上・llog'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libjniutils.so] Error 1
```

Which I guess is just some garbage from memory, like a string /variable hasn't been addressed correctly.

I'm very new to jni, so I'm at a bit of a loss of how to troubleshoot this.

---

Code follows:

JniUtils.java

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.ndk;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
public class JniUtils {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jniutils");
    }
    public static native void log(String tag, String message);
    public static native void copy(ByteBuffer dst, float[] src, int offset, int len);
}
```

jniutils.cpp

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "jniutils.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_badlogic_androidgames_ndk_JniUtils_log
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring tag, jstring message) {
    const char *cTag = env-> GetStringUTFChars(tag, 0);
    const char *cMessage = env-> GetStringUTFChars(message, 0);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, cTag, cMessage);
    env-> ReleaseStringUTFChars(tag, cTag);
    env-> ReleaseStringUTFChars(message, cMessage);
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_badlogic_androidgames_ndk_JniUtils_copy
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject dst, jfloatArray src, jint offset, jint len) {
    unsigned char* pDst = (unsigned char*)env-> GetDirectBufferAddress(dst);
    float* pSrc = (float*)env-> GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(src, 0); memcpy(pDst,
    pSrc + offset, len * 4);
    env-> ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(src, pSrc, 0);
}
```

application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jniutils
LOCAL_LDLIBS := − llog
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jniutils.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: `LOCAL_LDLIBS := − llog`  <-- that's supposed to be `-llog` (note the regular hypen instead of an en-dash, and no space).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but no change in results at all. 
LOCAL_LDLIBS : - llog and LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog both produce the same result.

I wondered if there's some out of bounds problem with the pointer manipulation.

memcpy(pDst, pSrc + offset, len * 4);

I'm not too comfortable with that number 4 hard-coded in there. I guess it's the size of some variable. A float?  An int? But I tried different numbers and still couldn't get it to work.

I might give up on this.... I'm copying an example from a book, but it doesn't have enough comments or explanation to understand line by line.

Comment: Oops. Finally got it working.  I retyped it again and it worked fine.  I'm using a Japanese keyboard, and if I accidentally set it in Japanese mode or hit the wrong key, I get something that looks like a hyphen but isn't.  Now I see what you were saying.  Thanks so much!!